# finding an exact match for string

Tags: python, regex, string, match

I used the following function to find the exact match for words in a string.

```
def exact_Match(str1, word):
    result = re.findall('\\b'+word+'\\b', str1, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    if len(result)>0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

exact_Match(str1, word)
```

But I get an exact match for both words "award" and "award-winning" when it only should be award-winning for the following string.

```
str1 = "award-winning blueberries"
word1 = "award"
word2 = "award-winning"
```

How can i get it such that re.findall will match whole words with hyphens and other punctuations?

Answer (score 7):

Make your own word-boundary:

```
def exact_Match(phrase, word):
    b = r'(\s|^|$)' 
    res = re.match(b + word + b, phrase, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    return bool(res)
```

copy-paste from here to my interpreter:

```
>>> str1 = "award-winning blueberries"
>>> word1 = "award"
>>> word2 = "award-winning"
>>> exact_Match(str1, word1)
False
>>> exact_Match(str1, word2)
True
```

Actually, the casting to `bool` is unnecessary and not helping at all. The function is better off without it:

```
def exact_Match(phrase, word):
    b = r'(\s|^|$)' 
    return re.match(b + word + b, phrase, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

---

note: `exact_Match` is pretty unconventional casing. just call it exact_match.

Comment: thanks for the comment. However, it doesn't seem to work. I put the code in and it's returning None for all cases.

Comment: @lost9123193 you probably did not copy the code, or made some changes. It works for me, and I have copied it from here.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your initial method is that `'\\b'` does not denote the zero-width assertion search that your looking for. (And if it did, I would use `r'\b'` instead because backslashes can become a real hassle in regular expressions - [see this link](http://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#the-backslash-plague))

From [Regular Expression HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#more-metacharacters)

`\b`

`Word boundary. This is a zero-width assertion that matches only at the beginning or end of a word. A word is defined as a sequence of alphanumeric characters, so the end of a word is indicated by whitespace or a non-alphanumeric character.`

Because `-` is a non-alphanumeric character, your findall regular expression will find `award` in `award-wining` but not in `awards`.

Depending on your searched phrase, I would also think of using `re.findall` instead of `re.match` as suggested by Elazar. In your example `re.match` works, but if the word you are looking for is nested anywhere beyond the beginning of the string, `re.match` will not succeed.