# getting an exact match from a list in python

Tags: python, regex, text, match

I am trying to extract the names from a block of text, since there are only few names that can ever occur it is quite easy to just preconstruct list of names and I would like to match them in a text. For example, I have the following list:

```
names = [ "Wim Duisenberg", "Jean-Claude Trichet", "Mario Draghi", "Christine Lagarde"]
```

And the following block of text that is scraped via beautiful soup:

```
print(textauthors)
<h2 class="ecb-pressContentSubtitle">Mario Draghi, President of the ECB, <br/>Vítor Constâncio, Vice-President of the ECB, <br/>Frankfurt am Main, 20 October 2016</h2>
```

I tried the following solution (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16765625/finding-an-exact-match-for-string) answer on stack overflow):

```
def exact_Match(textauthors, names):
b = r'(\s|^|$)' 
res = return re.match(b + word + b, phrase, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print(res)
```

It gives me an error of incorrect syntax and I am not sure how to solve it. Also let me in advance apologize if there is already answer for this somewhere on stack overflow, I am python beginner and I am not really sure how to even search for the right question. When I search for matching of names I see answers which try to do it with nltk but that is not really appropriate for me where I want to get exact match and when I try to search for match based on string text I cant find the answer that would work for me.

Comment: The syntax error should be pointing exactly what the issue is: `res = return <somethign>` makes no sense. Either assign or return.

Comment: In addition, you probably shouldn't be using regex directly against HTML.

Comment: A duplicate of [Match a whole word in a string using dynamic regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29996079/match-a-whole-word-in-a-string-using-dynamic-regex)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I actually found that question but it did not worked for me. Maybe it’s because it uses python 2 and I use 3 or maybe it’s because I miss-applied the code from there. Before this post I actually tried a lot of other SE answers. But If you think this is still duplicate then vote to close it.

Comment: The solution there is for Python 3, too. See https://ideone.com/zUTj2o

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew oh okay then I don’t understand what I did wrong... then please close this. I don’t want to delete it so people who got upvotes don’t loose their points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you authors from textauthors:

```
import re

textauthors = '<h2 class="ecb-pressContentSubtitle">Mario Draghi, President of the ECB, <br/>Vítor Constâncio, Vice-President of the ECB, <br/>Frankfurt am Main, 20 October 2016</h2>'
regex = r">(?P<name>[^\s]+\s[^\s]+),"
matches = re.findall(regex, textauthors)
print(matches) # ['Mario Draghi', 'Vítor Constâncio']
```

of course if you need to extract authors from your textauthors